# JS Build If (conditions) dynamically according to different array contents

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

**JS**

```js
let data1 = [{'id' : '0001', 'area' : 'Paris', 'price' : '100', 'year': '2022'}]
//should construct condition if(id === '0001' && area === 'Paris' && price === '100 && year === '2022')

let data2 = [{'price' : '300', 'year': '2021'}]
//should construct condition if(price === '300' && year === '300')

let data3 = [{'area' : 'Athens'}]
//should construct condition if(area === 'Athens')
// no && when we have only one condition

//my code attempt fo far

let ArrayNew = [];
let operator_and = ' && ';

for(let i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
  ArrayNew += data1.map(x => Object.keys(x) + ' === ' + operator_and);
}

console.log('if ('+ ArrayNew +')'); // if (id,area,price,year ===  && )
```

**Question**

I am trying to build dynamically conditions inside an if() statement according not only to the number of keys but also to the keys of each given array.

I expect to create something like this

`if  (generated_conditions) { .... }`

Comment: `eval` comes to mind, but it's generally a bad idea to use eval in most cases. why don't you tell us what you are trying to do with this? there may be a better, simpler solution

Comment: @nullptr build an if (condition or conditions) according to URL params when and which they exist but I think the general context does not change whatever the case is. For ex.         .    

/search?id=0001 , or /search?id=0001&area=Paris&price=100 , or /search?area=Paris

that part is already made, passing the existing URL params into an array (for ex. data1)

Comment: You can loop over url parameters and do `if (data1[urlParam] === urlParamValue)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be try something like this

```js
let data1 = [{'id' : '0001', 'area' : 'Paris', 'price' : '100', 'year': '2022'}]

data1.forEach((item) => {
  let condition = '';
  let keys = Object.keys(item);
  keys.map((k) => {
    if (condition) {
      condition += ` && ${k} == ${item[k]}`
    } else {
      condition = `${k} == ${item[k]}`
    }

  })
  console.log(condition)
})
```